# Jenkins Publishing Multi Module Spock Test Reports

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, spock, spock-reports

I have a multi-module maven project that looks like this:

```
backend
|_module-a
|_module-b
|_module-c
```

Eventually new modules can be added under backend

The backend module has a packaging "pom" and all modules-a,b and c are just regular jars

We use [Spock](http://spockframework.org/) as a testing framework and have spock reports generated by each module: (module-a/target/spock-reports for example for module a) 
Specifically we use [This framework](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports) for generating spock reports

Now I would like to create a Jenkins Job for module **backend** that would build all modules and publish an **aggregated** test report.

I Do use "Publish JUnit Test Result report" Post build action, but I do want to take advantage of HTMLs generated by spock reporting framework and show then in jenkins.

So my question is basically how do you I achieve this behavior?

Thanks a lot in advance